# FileSystemProvider auto-create directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on implementing this the File System provider functionality:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider

I'd like the following writeFile function to automatically create any necessary parent directories as needed.  Was wondering if any one else has done anything similar, or how the experts would approach it.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/aa42c2ec7248059ff5903ff11aa6eeabc04329bf/fsprovider-sample/src/fileSystemProvider.ts#L80

Option 1:

- change the following line to silent=true and if it returns an undefined, create the necessary directory
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/aa42c2ec7248059ff5903ff11aa6eeabc04329bf/fsprovider-sample/src/fileSystemProvider.ts#L199

option 2:

- Extend the logic of this if statement or replace the following error with some logic to create the folders
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/aa42c2ec7248059ff5903ff11aa6eeabc04329bf/fsprovider-sample/src/fileSystemProvider.ts#L183

thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the following function.  I tried the follow the existing code style and approach for simplicity.

```js
    /**
     * make parent directires if not present
     */
    private _makePath(uri: Uri) {
        // get the base directory
        const dirname = uri.with({ path: path.posix.dirname(uri.path) });

        // split the base directory to the folder parts
        const parts = dirname.path.split('/');

        // array to hold the parent folders as we create them
        const fullPath: string[] = [];

        // loop through folders
        for ( const part of parts) {
            if (!part) {
                continue;   // empty part, continue with loop
            }

            // track the folder path as we check/create them
            fullPath.push(part);

            // see if current folder exists
            const here = this._lookup(Uri.parse(...fullPath), true);
            if (!here) {
                // current folder not found, so create it
                this.createDirectory(Uri.parse(path.join(...fullPath)));
            } else {
                console.log('directory exists already: ', part);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call the function at each file creation:

```js
    writeFile(uri: vscode.Uri, content: Uint8Array, options: { create: boolean, overwrite: boolean }, id?: string): void {
        console.log('writefile: ', uri);
        const basename = path.posix.basename(uri.path);

        //  *** create dir path if not there ***
        this._makePath(uri);

        const parent = this._lookupParentDirectory(uri);
        let entry = parent.entries.get(basename);
        if (entry instanceof Directory) {
            throw vscode.FileSystemError.FileIsADirectory(uri);
        }
        if (!entry && !options.create) {
            throw vscode.FileSystemError.FileNotFound(uri);
        }
        if (entry && options.create && !options.overwrite) {
            throw vscode.FileSystemError.FileExists(uri);
        }
        if (!entry) {
            entry = new File(basename, id); 
            parent.entries.set(basename, entry);
            this._fireSoon({ type: vscode.FileChangeType.Created, uri });
        }
        entry.mtime = Date.now();
        entry.size = content.byteLength;
        entry.data = content;

        this._fireSoon({ type: vscode.FileChangeType.Changed, uri });
    }
```